# VBA OOP How can I make subproperties

Tags: vba, class, properties

How can I program my class module so that I can call properties on properties?

I'm not sure I'm using the right terminology, so I will try to clarify. In MsAccess whenever I want to manipulate elements on a form I can reference them using a period to separate each objects. For example, if I wanted to change the value of a text box I can call:

```
form("formname").txtboxname.value = "new value"
```

So it's like I have a form object that has a textbox object that has a value object.

How could I achieve this in my own class module.

My specific example is that I have stored an array in a private variable in the class however I cannot simply use a Property GET to return an array. (And I don't want to make it public because the array is programmatically populated) But if I want to iterate I need to know the Ubound and Lbound value of that array.

I would rather avoid having to store the Ubound and Lbound values in their own variable as that seems a waste.

How could I somehow program the class in order to get a ?subclass?

so that if I want the ubound or lbound I could call something like

```
set x = mycls
debug.? x.pArrayVariable.getLBound
```

Even the right terminology for what I'm trying to do could get me closer to an answer, I've tried searching for properties and sub properties but I'm not sure that's getting me somewhere.

Example of my class: mycls

```
Private pArrayVariable() as string

public property get pArrayVariable() as string
  'Run Code to Populate array here
  Array() = pArray()
end property
```

Is something called "Collections" what I'm asking about?

Comment: The TextBox in the form is not a subclass, it is a member of that class. The term you may be looking for is "composition". The form is composed of other objects. This is one of the ways we achieve reuse in OOP. The rest of your question I don't really understand. "Collections" are just that - collections of objects. A form is not a collection. An array is a type of collection. You could have array of forms though i.e. a collection of forms.

Comment: ...and `Value` is a Variant property, not an object

Comment: If you want to call "Properties on Properties" then the first Property call will need to return an object which itself has properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a property can return an object (like a user class) which has its own properties. Example below:

Here is the code for a class called `MinMax`

```
Private m_min As Integer
Private m_max As Integer

Public Property Get MinValue() As Integer
    MinValue = m_min
End Property
Public Property Let MinValue(ByVal x As Integer)
    m_min = x
End Property
Public Property Get MaxValue() As Integer
    MaxValue = m_max
End Property
Public Property Let MaxValue(ByVal x As Integer)
    m_max = x
End Property

Public Sub SetMinMax(ByVal min_value As Integer, ByVal max_value As Integer)
    m_min = min_value
    m_max = max_value
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_min = 0
    m_max = 1
End Sub
```

and here is the code for a class named `MyClass`. Notice how it exposes a property of type `MinMax`

```
Private m_target As MinMax
Private m_name As String

Public Property Get Target() As MinMax
    Target = m_target
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = m_name
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_target = New MinMax
    m_name = vbNullString
End Sub

Public Sub SetValues(ByVal a_name As String, ByVal min_value As Integer, ByVal max_value As Integer)
    m_name = a_name
    m_target.SetMinMax min_value, max_value
End Sub
```

Now the main code can have a statement like

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim t As New MyClass
    t.SetValues "Mary", 1, 100

    Debug.Print t.Target.MinValue, t.Target.MaxValue
End Sub
```

Comment: So it's an object with another object inside. I don't know if I'm going too far with this question but in the case where I build an MSAcces form. Each time I add a textbox I'm creating a new object (TextBox) within that first object (Form). How is that dynamically allocated without first setting up the Private m_target as MinMax.  So to Simplify. How do you add an object to a class. Because there's always form.txbx1 and form.txbx2. I'm not sure how you would allocate those two properties without hard coding them? (Of course, I might be comparing apples to oranges if this isn't how forms work)

Comment: `VBE` takes care of adding fields to the form of control types as you add things to the designer. Why do you care about the internals? Creating a dynamic UI that changes at runtime is quite hard in `VBA` but trivial in [tag:winforms].

Comment: Thanks for all the info, I was wondering whether or not the winforms object was written in the same way as VBA but it seems like you confirm my suspicion that it's a different type of beast.

Answer (score 0):

I still am curious about my original question above, however it came out of a problem of not being able to access the array. Seems I am incorrect.

You can use

```
Public Property Get ArrayVariable() As String()
  Call 'code to populate array
  ArrayVariable= pArrayVariable() 'Notice the paren here
End Property
```

And then to reference the array

```
debug.? ubound(clsvar.ArrayVariable()) 'Notice paren here too
or
debug.? clsvar.ArrayVariable()(1) 'Notice the parens here too
```